# Which partition should be at top /boot or swap partition?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partition, swap, home

I am installing Ubuntu and I was confused while partition that which partition should be at top /boot or swap partition?

Because I want maximum performance.

And is it good to create/home partition logical?

Because I have mbr disk and three primary partitions can only be made.

Comment: At top of what?

Comment: If your disk is spinning rust, there is a case for having the swap partition on the "lower" cylinders, since these are on the outer part of the platters and can be "faster" on such disks, and faster swap is usually a *good thing™* - as for having an "mbr disk" ... you do know, if you're using the whole disk, you can make it GPT if you want (if supported by the BIOS of course)

Comment: So first swap then /boot partition?

Comment: If you have more than 4GB of RAM, you may never user swap. If less RAM, you may want a lighter weight flavor. Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours I started using gpt in 2010 with BIOS only system. It then also requires a 1MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. If drive may be used later with newer UEFI system add ESP - efi system partition now for future use.